# Passing parameters at runtime dagger 2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a module, `UserModule` that takes in a string and provides a user object.

UserModule:

```
@Module
class UserModule(val name: String) {
    @Provides
    fun provideUser() : User = User(name = name)
}
```

And a `ViewModelComponent` that has `UserModule` as one of its components

ViewModelComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [UserModule::class])
interface ViewModelComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

Normally I would provide the component in my application like this:

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var component: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .userModule(UserModule("Name"))
                    .build()
    }
}
```

And reference it in my activity like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var user: User

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        (application as MainApplication).component.inject(this)
}
```

However, this assumes that the value of `UserModule` name is known at runtime and is hardcoded into `MainApplication`, however, in reality, the value of name is obtained from `MainActivity`.

The only solution I can think of is to build the dependency graph in `MainActivity` so I am able to pass name like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var user: User

    val newUserName = "NewName"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .userModule(UserModule(newUserName))
                    .build()    
        component.inject(this)
}
```

This solution seems very unefficient but it is the only way I can inject dynamic parameters in Dagger 2. Is there a better way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue aswell, first solution that I thought of was to create some "static holder" class that would hold dynamic parameters and it would be developers responsibility to update this holder at the right time - before injection happens I guess. I didnt actually try it though and it doesnt seem to be too clean either.

Anway after a bit of googling I found this article: https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-module-parameters-7c820d944a which seems to be more "dagger oriented" solution, didnt try that either, but it's something you can start with.

I would only comment this but I dont have required reputation...